# Appending text to date in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to append some text to excel cell.

> For example if the cell A1 has the date 17-Jan-12 , the formula should
>   append text to the date as "17-Jan-12 today" .

No matter what I try I get the datevalue of the date and then text appended like this - `

> "40912 today"

How do I get this?

This is what I am doing

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,"    Today")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel stores dates as numbers: that's why you're seeing that behaviour.  You want something like this (adjust format to suit):

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd-mmm-yy") & " today"
```

Answer (score 1):

That numerical value is the internal way that excel stores the date cell. To render this as text (so that you can append other text), you must apply a conversion:

```
=TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy"),"          Today")
```

Where A1 is your date cell. There is more information about the formatter string (the second argument to TEXT()) in the [Text function documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx).